# Intersection Coordinates with \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, intersections

I am trying to extract the coordinate of an intersection point (Int1) and add it to a plot as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\def\cdf(#1)(#2)(#3){0.5*(1+(erf((#1-#2)/(#3*sqrt(2)))))}%
% to be used: \cdf(x)(mean)(variance)

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
      xlabel=$t$,
      ylabel=$\Phi(t)$,
      xmin=1,
      xmax=8,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1.1,
      grid=none,
      legend entries={CDF, A},legend pos=north west, legend style={draw=none}, legend cell align={left}
      ]
      \def\mean{4};
      \def\var{1};
      %
      \addplot[smooth, thick, red, name path global=cdf]  gnuplot{\cdf(x)(\mean)(\var)};
      %
      %% Draw horizontal line to intersect cdf, then drop perp onto xaxis
      \path[name path global = lx1] (0, 0.6) --  (5, 0.6);
      \draw[dashed, gray, name intersections={ of=cdf and lx1, by = {Int1} }] (Int1)  (0, 0.6) -- (Int1);
      \draw[dashed, gray] (Int1) --  (Int1|-{(0, 0)}); % the curly protects the ()

      %% Does not work
      % \addplot[only marks, red, mark=*] coordinates \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{Int1};

      % Works
      \addplot[only marks, red, mark=*] coordinates {(4.2, 0.6)};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I have pgfplots 1.16, Texlive 2018,  shell escape is enabled. Please help.
Edit: I have looked the manual but the only use cases are where it is being used to label a node. I want to know how to use the coordinates in a plot.

Answer (score 1):

These are expansion issues, I think. That is, the coordinates are not yet "done" when they are needed. (BTW, you'd also have to add brackets: `\addplot[only marks, red, mark=*] coordinates {\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(Int1)}};`  but this does not fix the issue.) Here is a workaround in which I draw an empty plot to get the legend entry and add the plot mark as a node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\def\cdf(#1)(#2)(#3){0.5*(1+(erf((#1-#2)/(#3*sqrt(2)))))}%
% to be used: \cdf(x)(mean)(variance)

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
      xlabel=$t$,
      ylabel=$\Phi(t)$,
      xmin=1,
      xmax=8,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1.1,
      grid=none,
      legend entries={CDF, A},
      legend pos=north west, legend style={draw=none}, legend cell align={left}
      ]
      \def\mean{4};
      \def\var{1};
      %
      \addplot[smooth, thick, red, name path global=cdf]  gnuplot{\cdf(x)(\mean)(\var)};
      %
      %% Draw horizontal line to intersect cdf, then drop perp onto xaxis
      \path[name path global = lx1] (0, 0.6) --  (5, 0.6);
      \draw[dashed, gray, name intersections={ of=cdf and lx1, by = {Int1} }] (Int1)  (0, 0.6) -- (Int1);
      \draw[dashed, gray] (Int1) --  (Int1|-{(0, 0)}); % the curly protects the ()
      \node[red] at (Int1) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
      \addplot[draw=none,only marks=mark=*,red] coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I already have this workaround, I posted the question to know what kind of object is \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(Int1)} and how do I use it ?

Comment: @me10240 Well, what is different from your workaround is that the coordinates are not hard coded. I really think that you cannot use these coordinates in a plot in the same axis environment. This has to do with the order in which pfgplots expands things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the `\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates` macro, in that it doesn't return a coordinate pair directly. What it does is to set the value of the keys `/data point/x` and `/data point/y`, and to retrieve a value you have to do e.g. `\pgfkeysvalueof{/data/point x}`. So you cannot use it the way you're trying to use it. I don't know how one could obtain those values for use in a plot though, my attempts failed.

Another workaround could be to do `\draw [red] plot[only marks, mark=*] coordinates {(Int1)};` and use `\addlegendimage` to get the legend entry. Output is same as marmot's answer.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\def\cdf(#1)(#2)(#3){0.5*(1+(erf((#1-#2)/(#3*sqrt(2)))))}%
% to be used: \cdf(x)(mean)(variance)

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  intmark/.style={ % for convenience
    mark options={red},only marks,mark=*
  }
]
\begin{axis}[%
  xlabel=$t$,
  ylabel=$\Phi(t)$,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=8,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1.1,
  grid=none,
  legend entries={CDF, A},
  legend pos=north west,
  legend style={draw=none},
  legend cell align={left},
]

  \newcommand\mean{4};
  \newcommand\var{1};
      %
  \addplot[thick, red, name path global=cdf, domain=1:5]  gnuplot{\cdf(x)(\mean)(\var)};
  \addlegendimage{intmark}


  \path[name path global = lx1] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0.6) --  (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 0.6);


  \draw[dashed, gray, name intersections={ of=cdf and lx1, by = {Int1} }] 
    (Int1 -| current axis.origin) -| (Int1 |- current axis.origin);
  \draw  plot[intmark] coordinates {(Int1)};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```